# How to understand star sign(*) in function's function argument?

Tags: c++, c

Here is what I confused:

```
extern int sigsegv_leave_handler (
    void (*continuation) (void*, void*, void*), 
    void* cont_arg1, void* cont_arg2, void* cont_arg3);
```

I don't understand `*continuation`, what's the use for `*` in `*continuation`

**update**

The full code is in "/usr/include/sigsegv.h" in linux

**update**

I use `sigsegv_leave_handler` like following:

```
void cont(void *fault_addr, void *arg1, void *arg2) {
//    rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "type err");
    rraise(SEGV, NULL);
}

int handle_segv(void *fault_addr, int serious) {
    sigsegv_leave_handler(cont, fault_addr, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: How do you call `sigsegv_leave_handler()`, what paramteres are you passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
void (*continuation) (void*, void*, void*)
```

is simply a declaration where `continuation` is a pointer to a function taking 3 `void *` pointers and not returning anything (*with `void` return type*).

This is how you declare pointers to functions,

```
RETURN_TYPE (*IDENTIFIER)(... PARAMETERS WITH THEIR TYPES AS USUAL ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

A useful tool to use is [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=extern+int+sigsegv_leave_handler+%28void+%28*%29+%28void*%2C+void*%2C+void*%29%2C+void*+%2C+void*+%2C+void*+%29%3B)

```
extern int sigsegv_leave_handler (void (*) (void*, void*, void*), void* , void* , void* );
```

> declare sigsegv_leave_handler as extern function (pointer to function (pointer to void, pointer to void, pointer to void) returning void, pointer to void, pointer to void, pointer to void) returning int

Or in other words, `sigsegv_leave_handler()` takes 4 arguments and returns an `int`.

```
1) pointer to a function which takes 3 void * pointers and returns void
void (*f) (void*, void*, void*) 

2) pointer to void
void *

3) pointer to void
void *

4) pointer to void
void *
```

> what's the use for * in *continuation?

To show that the argument is a pointer to a function.

```
void (*continuation) (void*, void*, void*),
```